# How do I shift the value of my char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, shift

What I'm trying to do is create an encryption method that shifts a char array taken from an input file by a determined amount of letters. I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the chars into ints and back.
THis is what I've got so far:

```
char [] sChar = new char[line.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < sChar.length; i++){
        String s = reader.next();
        sChar = s.toCharArray();
        if(Character.isLetter(sChar[i])) {
            char c = 'a';
            int b = c;
            sChar[i] += key;
```

Comment: Not the most bullet proof encryption.

Comment: If you are encrypting, xor is better: `sChar[i] ^= key;`. To get the orignal, just do `sChar[i] ^= key;` again.

Comment: I would recommend looking into actual encryption, unless you're just doing this for coding practice - as a sort of exercise.

Comment: To change an int `i` to a char do: `char c = (char) i;`

Comment: It's more coding practice, I'm a complete beginner

Comment: Thanks! I've got the sChar[i} ^= key; working for me now. Is there a way I can get it to wrap around so it goes back to the beginning of alphabet if passes the end?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are thinking.

I thought conversion int to character and back would be easy.
Just to freshen up the idea I checked

```
    char xdrf = 'a';
    System.out.println((int)xdrf); // output is 97
    int idrf= 99;
    xdrf = (char)idrf;
    System.out.println(xdrf); // output is c
```

also if you key is a character you can directly sum it therefore statement

```
 schar[i] += key;
```

should be good

more to it

```
    idrf = idrf + 'd';
    System.out.println(idrf); //output is 199
```

further using

```
 System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(idrf-20)); //output is 3
```

this all is working by ascii value. I am unsure if you would like ascii values to be used.